# Hundreds of Redis instances on the same server

Tags: memory, redis, scalability, multicore, sharding

Is this doable or will this degrade CPU performance?

The reason I want to do this is presharding. I want to shard my data across many (128, or possibly 256) Redis instances, and then run them all on the same server. Then when I need to scale out I can just fire up more servers and easily move the instances to other servers.

I know Redis itself has a small memory footprint so memory overhead would presumably not be a problem. But if I have just 4 cores, would they be handle hundreds of Redis instances? Or should I maintain a max of one instance per core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis works like **single-threaded** application, it forks additional threads for e.g. I/O. So I would say that it could work **one core per one redis** instance just fine. As you still share some resources on multi-core computer among cores. So you can barely achieve same performance, but I don't see problem here.

The problem could appear once you would switch "durability" on to [allow persistence](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) to you hard drive. Even if redis itself uses new forked thread to provide persistence, I don't believe that it would not hurt performance a lot for loaded system.

As I've already said, it could work pretty well w/o persistence.